# Cypress: POST Request not being intercepted

Tags: automated-tests, cypress

My test is making a POST request to login via API, the URL is the same as the one in the interception, but the request isn't getting intercepted no matter what I do. Any ideas why? My test calls `loginAPI()` in a beforeEach hook and I get 403 response because the request never gets intercepted so I can set a Header.

```
Cypress.Commands.add('getSessionCookie', (emailAddress: string, password: string) => {
  cy.task('createAndAccessSecret', Cypress.env('version')).then((cfToken) => {
    cy.setHeaderQA()
    cy.request('POST', Cypress.env("authBaseUrlApi") + "sign-in ", {
      email: emailAddress,
      password: password,
      cf_token: cfToken
    }).then((response) => {
      return response.headers['set-cookie'];
    })
  })
})

Cypress.Commands.add('setHeaderQA', () => {
  const {headerKey, headerValue } = Cypress.env();
  cy.log(`Header: ${headerKey} ${headerValue}`);
  cy.intercept('POST', 'https://auth.website.dev/v2/sign-in', (req) => {
    cy.log(`Intercepted request: ${req.method} ${req.url}`);
    req.headers[headerKey] = headerValue;
  })
})

Cypress.Commands.add('loginAPI', (emailAddress: string, password: string, { cacheSession = true } = {}) => {
  const login = () => {
    cy.getSessionCookie(emailAddress, password).then((cookies => {
      cookies.forEach(cookie => {
        const firstPart = cookie.split(';')[0]
        const separator = firstPart.indexOf('=')
        const name = firstPart.substring(0, separator)
        const value = firstPart.substring(separator + 1)
        console.debug('cookie', name, value)
        cy.setCookie('__session', value)
      })
    }))
  }
  if (cacheSession) {
    cy.session([emailAddress, password], login)
  } else {
    login()
  }
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@aladin has a correct work around, but the bigger picture IMO is that the code is over-complicated.

Since `cy.loginAPI()` controls the process, just pass in the stored `Cypress.env()` values.

Use the format `cy.request(options)` to add the header if passed in.

Note, it would be better if `{headerKey, headerValue}` were stored in `Cypress.env()` as a key/value pair.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('getSessionCookie', 
  (
    emailAddress: string, 
    password: string, 
    header?: object           <- optional
  ) => {
  cy.task('createAndAccessSecret', Cypress.env('version')).then((cfToken) => {

    const requestOptions = {
      method: 'POST', 
      url: Cypress.env("authBaseUrlApi") + "sign-in ",
      body: {
        email: emailAddress,
        password: password,
        cf_token: cfToken
      }
    }
    if (header) {
      const {headerKey, headerValue} = header;
      requestOptions.headers[headerKey] = headerValue;
    }

    cy.request(requestOptions).then((response) => {
        ...
})

Cypress.Commands.add('loginAPI', (...) => {
  const login = () => {
    const {headerKey, headerValue} = Cypress.env()
    cy.getSessionCookie(emailAddress, password, {headerKey, headerValue})
      .then((cookies => {
        ...
})
```

Comment: The header is actually always required now so this approach makes more sense rather than intercepting, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If I understand, you want to intercept the request sent by

```js
cy.request('POST', Cypress.env("authBaseUrlApi") + "sign-in ", {...
```

with the `cy.intercept()` further down.

If so, no - it doesn't work at least with e2e tests. I think that's because the test runs in one window and the app in another (which is why there is `cy.window()` to access the app's window).

If you change the `cy.request()` to use `window.fetch()`, then `cy.intercept()` ***will*** catch it. I often use it to spot-test intercepts independently of the app.

Off the top of my head

```js
cy.window().then(async (win) => {
  const url = `${Cypress.env("authBaseUrlApi")}sign-in`
  const response = await win.fetch(url, {
    method: "POST",
    body: {
      email: emailAddress,
      password: password,
      cf_token: cfToken
    }
  })
  return response.headers['set-cookie']
  // or maybe 
  cy.wrap(response.headers['set-cookie'])
})
```

Comment: It isn't that "the test runs in one window and the app in another". The request isn't intercepted because `cy.intercept` only captures requests from the application. To put it simply, `cy.intercept` doesn't intercept `cy.request` -> https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept

Comment: Yes we know that `cy.intercept` does not catch `cy.request` - that's the point of the question. But if you actually run this code, it works - so evidence indicates it *is* caused by the different window objects for the test code and the app.

Comment: D'accord, intercept is done by proxy object - it's why you cannot intercept requests from the test window. The app has a different window object, it's the one that has the proxy applied.

Comment: @AladinSpaz I don't think that OP knows that `cy.intercept` does not catch `cy.request`. Their question is why does their code, which tries to use `cy.intercept` to catch `cy.request`, not work. At no point did I say your code did not work, but I was adding clarity on the _reason why OP's code does not work_, as I did not feel your answer provided that entirely.

Comment: George asked ***Any ideas why?*** and I gave my reason, but you said ***It isn't that...*** and I am pointing out that the evidence contradicts your comment.